# How to subset a data frame, apply a function with a for-loop and obtain the result with the name of each subset on it?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data set where I want to subset it by some conditions as TRT and then evaluate some functions on each one, but instead of repeat the function for every subset I rather to do a for loop. The thing is that I want to get the result but with the name of the subset on it, and I cannot do it

This is my script and the result:

```
df_list <- split(dataet,(dataet$TRT))
> for (i in df_list){
+         a <-  c(shapiro.test(i$FV0)$p.value)
+        print(a)
+ }
[1] 0.07373223
[1] 0.2995577
[1] 0.003565924
[1] 0.005733235
[1] 0.02378732
[1] 0.01615178
[1] 0.09363349
[1] 0.8619091
```

The problem above is that the results are ok, but I cannot obtain those values separated.Then i was trying to paste the names of df_list with the vector (a), but I just got the last result:

```
> paste(names(df_list),a)
[1] "27D 0.861909062310829" "27S 0.861909062310829"
[3] "34D 0.861909062310829" "34S 0.861909062310829"
[5] "38D 0.861909062310829" "38S 0.861909062310829"
[7] "45D 0.861909062310829" "45S 0.861909062310829"
```

This is part of my data frame:

```
> head(dataet)
ID     sp IND POS Temp TRT   FV0   FVf      Prop
1  1 DIPOLE   A   D  27C 27D 0.833 0.664 0.2028812
2  2 DIPOLE   A   D  27C 27D 0.843 0.622 0.2621590
3  3 DIPOLE   A   D  27C 27D 0.843 0.525 0.3772242
4  4 DIPOLE   A   D  27C 27D 0.813 0.601 0.2607626
5  5 DIPOLE   A   D  27C 27D 0.810 0.592 0.2691358
6  6 DIPOLE   A   D  27C 27D 0.845 0.663 0.2153846
> tail(dataet)
 ID     sp IND POS Temp TRT   FV0   FVf      Prop
235 285 DIPOLE   C   S  45C 45S 0.764 0.383 0.4986911
236 286 DIPOLE   C   S  45C 45S 0.772 0.411 0.4676166
237 287 DIPOLE   C   S  45C 45S 0.748 0.073 0.9024064
238 288 DIPOLE   C   S  45C 45S 0.757 0.125 0.8348745
239 289 DIPOLE   C   S  45C 45S 0.773 0.086 0.8887451
240 290 DIPOLE   C   S  45C 45S 0.772 0.188 0.7564767
```

Comment: what eactly is `df_list`

Comment: sorry, I didn´t include that in the script... it´s where i split my data frame         df_list <- split(dataet,(dataet$TRT))

Comment: No worries. Probably a good idea to edit the question with this information so others can see it.

Comment: The value of "a" is just the one created at the end of the loop. Since you were not storing the results by assigning for an indexed value your just get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
df_list <- split(dataet,(dataet$TRT))
res <- list()

for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
         res[[i]] <-  c( names(df_list[i], 
                         shapiro.test(df_list[[i]]$FV0)$p.value 
                        )

                             }
res
```

Not a highly efficient way to use loops but I'm guessing you task is of modest size. Could pre-allocate with `res<-vector('list', length=length(df_list) )` if you needed more efficiency.